# Cannot move cursor in Insert mode

Tags: vim, vi

Just noted I can't move cursor to left or right (up and down works correctly) in Insert mode while editing an .sql file, with other files it works ok also.

Any hint?.

Vim: 7.2.330 - Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64

Answer (score 2):

Install "vim". It lets you to traverse text within "insert mode" using arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `<Left>` and `<Right>` are mapped to something else?  Try this while editing an SQL file:

```
:imap <Left>
```

That should tell you if it's mapped to anything.  You can unmap it like

```
:iunmap <Left>
```

If some syntax file is mapping `<Left>` and `<Right>` strangely, you might have to track it down and edit it, or else set up `.vimrc` to override these mappings (e.g. via an autocmd).

Comment: Thanks Brian, :imap gives this "i  <Left>   @<C-R>=sqlcomplete#DrillOutOfColumns()<CR>", but when I do :iunmap <Left> it shows "E31: No such mapping."